# After following Guru's tutorial, the reflections and shadows look weird in the render view

Tags: cycles-render-engine, shadows, reflection

I finished the part where you make the coffee cup, the plate, all glass, then add a liquid, etc
Now I was supposed to move onto where I turn that liquid into coffee and such
But I noticed weird artifacts, and textures that are not supposed to be there, in the render view
My normals are good, blue
This question might have been asked previously but no answers fixed it for me, as I tried deleting the denoise node, same one as he put in the tutorial series, tried to increase the samples, by a lot, 1000+
Using both high samples and the denoise node, etc
While increase the samples kinda made it better, but it's still far from what his result was..
I also tried removing completely the liquid from the scene, but even the coffee cup and plate alone look weird.
It's almost like those random textures showing up in render view are from the materials preview tab, where a forest or whatever pops on your glass to let you know its a reflective material

[image]